# Having trouble displaying Multiple Home Card Display on Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, amazon-echo

Previously when I gave command to alexa for a search. I was just getting 5 items in response. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Than I showed a image of 1st item with 5 items in response. 
For a response having single card, The card image and card value is shown perfectly fine. Screenshot Attached.

[image]

But I want to show 5 images for each 5 items. Which is not possible in one single card as one card can only have one image. Also for one call , only one response can be given which can have one card. Multiple response for one call won't work.

Here is what I wanna try but not sure if alexa has this feature.

1. I give a command to alexa to find something.
2. I get 5 items in response for that command.
3. This 5 items in response, I want to use as auto command (Alexa will automatically execute a call for each item received, instead of prompting user to say or give command) and execute 5 calls. to which I will get 5 response each having a card. Thus this 5 cards will have 5 images attached to it.

DO alexa have a Auto command option which I can trigger as I get a response, I cannot find it in Doc.

Any other approach If I can try ?

Anyone there to Help ? Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of the Alexa Skills Kit, you an only return a single card per response. And that card can only have a single image. Additionally, you can only respond once per user input. The user has to make another request before your skill can respond again.

So the only way to do something like this would be to invoke your skill and give one result, but prompt the user to say "next" for additional results. That way the user can scroll through as many results as they want. Each with its own reply and card.